# Creating animation of a swimming pool with a pipe supplying water

Tags: fluid-simulation

I've only been using Blender for a few months, and the fluid simulation for only a few days.

I've made a bit of progress in creating a video of a swimming pool with a pipe supplying water. This is the insirpation:

[image: Therme Vals in Switzerland]

I've struggled with tutorials as they are usually showing a faucet or tap filling an empty bowl. To get around this, I've created a very shallow block only a few inches deep and set it up as a fluid and inflow, fitting within the domain. I created a bent pipe, and inside inserted a small cube that supplies the water and also set it up as a fluid, and inflow.

Overall the performance is more or less what I'm looking for, but I can't get the flow to be refined enough. No matter the size of the little cube inside the pipe, the water flowing out is just too large of a volume, and thus I have to create a gigantic, and less elegant looking pipe. Note the image attached was when I set up the pool to fill all the way up from the bottom and it created weird dark splotches on a diagonal axis from the pipe to the lower right. I ran that simulation at a resolution of 128.

[image]

Assuming that I needed to I needed more detail I pumped things up to 256. It was a tiny bit better, but still not what I was looking for. I added bubbles etc... and some fog to make it feel like a mineral pool on a cold day.

[image]

At 256 I notice the flow isn't as smooth. It's a bit delayed coming out of the pipe (takes about 50 frames to come out) and at 512 it randomly spits out water and spray over a 250 frame range. Its like a pipe that's actually got some serious plumbing issues and doesn't flow consistently. I also find that running the resolution at 512 creates more of an orange peel like effect on the water. Note in the picture immediately after, it's a few frames after and only comes out as a spray.

[image]

[image]

Long story short, I can't refine the flow to the dimension I'd like, and adding more detail seems to make the flow a bit more erratic. I find 256 seems to be the sweet spot, I'd like to create something where the water flows out of a 2" pipe and not 8".

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I made some progress and I think I figured out a few things:

1. I used a cube ( as I saw in an example) and not a sphere for the inflow object. Replacing it with a sphere made a huge difference.
2. The surface emission needs to be turned on. I find a setting of 0.6 works, but I've gotten it down to 0.4 (although looks a bit too thin for me).
3. Is planar needs to be turned off.
4. Free-ing the bake might not be enough. I've gone in and deleted the old cache folder each time I've restarted a bake. It seems to create a more stable simulation without the random starting and stopping of flow.

A lot of instructional videos don't seem to cover points 2 and 3. In fact I think they might be new settings as I don't even see them shown in videos.

I think I've got the flow I'm more or less looking for. I'd like a bit more velocity out of the pipe, which I can tweak.

If anyone has suggestions to improve, I'd love to hear them!

[image]

Comment: Instead of a volume you can emit from a plane - enable ‘planar’ and specify the initial velocity to point the water out of the pipe. This might give morn consistent results. I haven’t played around with fluid sims on the later versions of Blender but I know this used to help back in “the old days” (a few years back). Hope this helps. I really like the look you’re going for - fluid sims can be a bit of a pain to get right. Make sure to “apply scale” to domain and objects and higher resolution is usually better. Good luck!!

Comment: Thanks Rich! I never actually thought of doing it from a plane. I'll give that a try tomorrow. It's been a few days of playing with the simulation and I need to do something else for a bit, haha.